# Dense set in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $ \Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $m(\Omega^c)=0 $. Then how can we show that $ \mathcal{F}(C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega))$ (here $ \mathcal{F}$ denotes the fourier transform) is dense in $L^2$(or $L^p$)?

Besides,  I'm also interested to know if the condition that $m(\Omega^c)=0$ can be weakened to some more general set.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The condition can't be weakened. As soon as the complement is of positive measure, the indicator function on that complement will be far in Lp terms. Rather, you need the condition mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with the case $\Omega=\Bbb R^n$, take $f\in L^2$. Then by Plancherel's theorem, theorem 12 [in these lecture notes](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/odiaz/notas/fourier), we can find $g\in L^2$ such that $f=\mathcal F g$. Now approximate $g$ by smooth functions with compact support and use isometry.